# Deleting an item with entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to delete an object using Entity Framework and on all the tutorials on the internet I found that in order to do that you have to call the `DeleteObject` method on the context. I tried doing that but it seems I have no `DeleteObject` methods.

Here is my code:

```
public void DeleteBook(int bookId)
    {
        Book book = (Book)bookContext.Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookId).First();
        bookContext.DeleteObject(book);
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> *'DataAccess.Models.BooksEntities' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'DataAccess.Models.BooksEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you take the `(Book)` cast off the `Book` assignment, change the `Book` variable to `var`, what type is shown when hovered over? I think you're using the wrong class.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you using a DbContext or an ObjectContext?  If you have a DbContext you need to use the [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) function:

```
public void DeleteBook(int bookId)
    {
        Book book = (Book)bookContext.Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookId).First();
        bookContext.Books.Remove(book);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add save changes.

Comment: You need to save changes: `bookContext.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 8):

**The probable solutions of deleting the entity without retrieving it By Changing State**

DbContext has methods called Entry and Entry, these methods get a DbEntityEntry for the given entity and provide access to the information about the entity and return a DbEntityEntry object able to perform the action on the entity. Now we can perform the delete operation on the context by just changing the entity state to EntityState.Deleted.

```
 using (Entities Context = new Entities())  
 {  
    Book  deptBook  = new Book  { Id  = bookId };  
    Context.Entry(deptBook).State = EntityState.Deleted;  
    Context.SaveChanges();  
 }
```