# Delete date from table in asp.net c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio

I have a little problem with delete from the table in my database.

I wrote the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBClassesDataContext db = new DBClassesDataContext();
        var qry = from m in db.pracownicies
                  where m.id == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])
                  select m;
        foreach (var q in qry)
        {
            db.pracownicies.DeleteOnSubmit(q);
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Unfortunately I received error:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

In my last application without the relationships everything works fine.

Here's diagram: [Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVwfC.jpg)

Comment: Which line throwing error ?

Comment: the entered code is in controller or where

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan [link](http://snag.gy/eu9GE.jpg) It's the screenshot.

Comment: @Anand Yes, It is in controller.

Comment: do you have values in 'qry' variable and can show the screen shot of the error. it will be helpful

Comment: Check InnerException for error details

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
    foreach (var q in qry)
    {
        db.pracownicies.DeleteObject(q);
    }    
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It gives error: CS1061 'Table<pracownicy>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Table<pracownicy>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Check the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227339/deleting-an-item-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
foreach (var q in qry)
{
    db.pracownicies.Remove(db.pracownicies.Find(q.id));
}    
db.SaveChanges();
```

It will delete the id's respective record in the table

Comment: It gives error: Error CS1061 'Table<pracownicy>' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'Table<pracownicy>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: import the required packages